# Shiny crashes when Run button is clicked - but only when starting in a certain tab

Tags: r, shiny, dt, rhandsontable

I'm having a really strange problem with my app. The UI is made up of 5 tabs. The first two contain RHandsontables which can be edited by the user and are used as input in the calculations. The last 3 contain DataTable outputs which are generated after the "Run" button is clicked.

If I open the app and click "Run" without clicking any of the tabs (i.e. leaving it on the default tab) the app crashes with the following message:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5554
Warning: Error in do.call: second argument must be a list
Stack trace (innermost first):
    67: do.call
    66: hot_to_r
    65: observeEventHandler [path/to/serverfile]
```

However if I open the app, click one of the other tabs, then navigate back to the first one and click "Run", the app runs without any issues. This doesn't make sense as by clicking into a different tab briefly and then back to the original one, nothing has actually changed with regards to inputs etc.

There are several `do.call("rbind", list)` functions in the server file and its quite difficult to pinpoint the one that's causing the problem. In none of them is it obvious that anything other than a list is being passed as the second argument.

My server and ui files are below. I have ommitted the bulk of the calculations and apologize that I can't fully reproduce the problem here. Just hoping that there is an obvious error in the structure of the app that someone might notice. Any suggestions welcome

**Server.R**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(rhandsontable)

# Server file for World Cup Outright App
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  values <- reactiveValues()


  output$Results <- renderRHandsontable({
    if (input$currentStage=="Group Stage"){
      rhandsontable(read.csv("path/to/file", colClasses = c('character','character','numeric','numeric')))
    }
    else if (input$currentStage=="Last 16"){
      rhandsontable(read.csv("path/to/file", colClasses = c('character','character','numeric','numeric')))
    }
    else{ 
      rhandsontable(read.csv("path/to/file", colClasses = c('character','character','numeric','numeric')))
    }
  })


  observeEvent(input$runButton,{
    values$results_table <- hot_to_r(input$Results)
  })



  output$Ratings <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(read.csv("path/to/file", colClasses=c('character','numeric','numeric','numeric','numeric')))

  })


  observeEvent(input$runButton,{
    values$ratings_table <- hot_to_r(input$Ratings)
  })


  price_markets <- eventReactive(input$runButton, {
    withProgress(message="Loading...",{

      t1 <- Sys.time()

      # Choose the number of simulations required
      sims <- as.numeric(input$simsInput)
      if(is.null(sims)){return()}

      Games <- read.csv("path/to/file",header = TRUE,colClasses = c('character','character','numeric','numeric'))
      ratingvratingfile <- read.csv("path/to/file", colClasses=c('numeric','numeric'),header=F,col.names=c('diff','prob1','prob2'))
      Last16Games <- read.csv("path/to/file",header = TRUE,colClasses = c('character','character','character','numeric','numeric'))
      QuarterFinalGames <- read.csv("path/to/file",header = TRUE,colClasses = c('character','character','character','numeric','numeric'))
      groupLookup <- read.csv("path/to/file", colClasses = c('character','character'))
      continentLookup <- read.csv("path/to/file", colClasses = c('character','character'))

      liveresults <- values$results_table
      liveLast16results <- values$results_table
      liveQFresults <- values$results_table
      ratingsfile <- values$ratings_table


      CurrentStage <- input$currentStage


      if(CurrentStage=="Group Stage"){

        # CALCULATIONS
      }



      if (CurrentStage=="Last 16"){

        # CALCULATIONS
     }

      if(CurrentStage=="Quarter Finals"){

        # CALCULATIONS

      }

      t2 <- as.numeric(difftime(Sys.time(), t1),units="mins")
      t2 <- round(t2,2)
      t2 <- paste0(as.character(t2)," minutes to run sims")


      # Put outputs in a list to be accessed by renderDataTable functions later
      list(groupApositions,groupAforecasts,groupAtricasts,
           groupBpositions,groupBforecasts,groupBtricasts,
           groupCpositions,groupCforecasts,groupCtricasts,
           groupDpositions,groupDforecasts,groupDtricasts,
           groupEpositions,groupEforecasts,groupEtricasts,
           groupFpositions,groupFforecasts,groupFtricasts,
           groupGpositions,groupGforecasts,groupGtricasts,
           groupHpositions,groupHforecasts,groupHtricasts,
           to_reach,stage_of_elim,name_the_finalists,t2,
           winners1,winners2)
    })
  })



  output$groupStagePositionTable <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group A"){
      table <- price_markets()[[1]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group B"){
      table <- price_markets()[[4]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group C"){
      table <- price_markets()[[7]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group D"){
      table <- price_markets()[[10]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group E"){
      table <- price_markets()[[13]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group F"){
      table <- price_markets()[[16]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group G"){
      table <- price_markets()[[19]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group H"){
      table <- price_markets()[[22]]
    }
    return(table)}),rownames=FALSE,options=list(pageLength=100,info=FALSE,paging=FALSE,searching=FALSE))


  output$groupStageForecastTable <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group A"){
      table <- price_markets()[[2]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group B"){
      table <- price_markets()[[5]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group C"){
      table <- price_markets()[[8]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group D"){
      table <- price_markets()[[11]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group E"){
      table <- price_markets()[[14]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group F"){
      table <- price_markets()[[17]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group G"){
      table <- price_markets()[[20]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group H"){
      table <- price_markets()[[23]]
    }
    return(table)}),rownames=FALSE,options=list(pageLength=100,info=FALSE,paging=FALSE,searching=FALSE))



  output$groupStageTricastTable <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group A"){
      table <- price_markets()[[3]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group B"){
      table <- price_markets()[[6]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group C"){
      table <- price_markets()[[9]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group D"){
      table <- price_markets()[[12]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group E"){
      table <- price_markets()[[15]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group F"){
      table <- price_markets()[[18]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group G"){
      table <- price_markets()[[21]]
    }
    if(input$groupMarkets=="Group H"){
      table <- price_markets()[[24]]
    }
    return(table)}),rownames=FALSE,options=list(pageLength=50,info=FALSE,paging=FALSE,searching=FALSE))


  output$outrightMarketTable <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable({
    if(input$outrightMarkets=="To Reach"){
      table1 <- price_markets()[[25]]
    }
    if(input$outrightMarkets=="Stage of Elimination"){
      table1 <- price_markets()[[26]]
    }
    if(input$outrightMarkets=="Name the Finalists"){
      table1 <- price_markets()[[27]]
    }
    return(table1)}),rownames=FALSE,options=list(paging=FALSE))


  output$winningGroupTable <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable({
    table <- price_markets()[[29]]
    return(table)
  }),rownames=FALSE,options=list(searching=FALSE,info=FALSE,paging=FALSE))


  output$winningContinent <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable({
    table <- price_markets()[[30]]
    return(table)
  }),rownames=FALSE,options=list(searching=FALSE,info=FALSE,paging=FALSE))



  output$timeElapsed <- renderText({price_markets()[[28]]})


})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(rhandsontable)

# User Interface for World Cup Outright App
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("World Cup Outright Simulator"),


  sidebarLayout(



    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('currentStage','Choose current stage',c("Group Stage","Last 16","Quarter Finals")),
      textInput("simsInput",label="Number of Simulations",value = 10000),
      actionButton("runButton","Run"),
      h2(textOutput("timeElapsed"))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Results",
                 rHandsontableOutput("Results")),
        tabPanel("Ratings",
                 rHandsontableOutput("Ratings")),
        tabPanel("Group Stage",
                 selectInput('groupMarkets','Choose Group',c("Group A", "Group B","Group C","Group D","Group E","Group F","Group G","Group H")),
                 h3("Group Positions"),
                 DT::dataTableOutput("groupStagePositionTable"),
                 h3("Group Forecasts"),
                 DT::dataTableOutput("groupStageForecastTable"),
                 h3("Group Tricasts"),
                 DT::dataTableOutput("groupStageTricastTable")

                 ),
        tabPanel("Outright",
                 selectInput('outrightMarkets','Choose Market',c("To Reach","Stage of Elimination","Name the Finalists")),
                 DT::dataTableOutput("outrightMarketTable")),

        tabPanel("Special",
                 h3("Winning Group"),
                 DT::dataTableOutput("winningGroupTable"),
                 h3("Winning Continent"),
                 DT::dataTableOutput("winningContinent"))

        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When objects are not visible on the page they are suspended (not executed) by default in shiny. Thus, you'll get an error when you try to use the output that is generated on any of the tabs you haven't opened yet. You can get around this with `outputOptions` see the reference [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/outputOptions.html). Note the following:

> suspendWhenHidden. When TRUE (the default), the output object will be suspended (not execute) when it is hidden on the web page. When FALSE, the output object will not suspend when hidden, and if it was already hidden and suspended, then it will resume immediately.

Basically the 4 tabs that are not on the screen are suspended and will not be rendered until you click on them.  This explains why when you click on them and go back you don't see the same error.  Add a line similar to this one at the bottom of your server script for each of the tabs you need rendered:

```
outputOptions(output, "Ratings", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

Comment: Fantastic. It seems odd that the default is TRUE, but I guess mine is just one case. Thanks